# kubectl secrets not accessible in React app Pods

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, environment-variables

I've tried to avoid, but really haven't had the need, to set specific env vars for a React FE. But I'm working on social authentication, with Azure AD specifically, and now I do have a use case for it.

I acknowledge the `AAD_TENANT_ID` and `AAD_CLIENT_ID` aren't exactly "secret" or sensitive information and will be compiled in the JS, but I'm trying to do this for a few reasons:

1. I can more easily manage dev and prod keys from a Key Vault...
2. Having environment independent code (i.e., `process.env.AAD_TENANT_ID` will work whether it is dev or prod).

But it doesn't work.

The issue I'm running into is that the env vars are not accessible at `process.env` despite having the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: admin-v2-deployment-dev
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: admin-v2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: admin-v2
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: admin-v2
          image: admin-v2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4001
          env:
            - name: AAD_CLIENT_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: app-dev-secrets
                  key: AAD_CLIENT_ID
            - name: AAD_TENANT_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: app-dev-secrets
                  key: AAD_TENANT_ID
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: admin-v2-cluster-ip-service-dev
  namespace: dev
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: admin-v2
  ports:
    - port: 4001
      targetPort: 4001
```

When I do the following anywhere in the code, it comes back `undefined`:

```
console.log(process.env.AAD_CLIENT_ID);
console.log(process.env.AAD_TENANT_ID);
```

The values are definitely there when I check secrets in the namespace and in the Pod itself:

```
    Environment:
      AAD_CLIENT_ID:  <set to the key 'AAD_CLIENT_ID' in secret 'app-dev-secrets'>  Optional: false
      AAD_TENANT_ID:  <set to the key 'AAD_TENANT_ID' in secret 'app-dev-secrets'>  Optional: false
```

So how should one go about getting kubectl secrets into React Pods?

Comment: Is your react app served by node.js? Do you get other environment variables?

Comment: For dev, it is using `npm start` in `Dockerfile.dev`. Using `npm build` for production in the `Dockerfile` and `nignx` to serve the static assets. The back-end is Django/DRF, but does not serve the FE.

Comment: react is running in the browser, you won't be able to get environment from a pod there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are using **create-react-app** app for React FE. You have to make sure that your environment variables starts with `REACT_APP_` else it will be ignored inside app.
According to create-react-app documentation

```
Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_.
Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally 
exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.
```

Source - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/